# Convert module-qualified OID to ObjectIdentity

Tags: pysnmp

How do you programatically convert module-qualified OIDs to ObjectIdentity?  I want to convert something like "IP-MIB::ipAdEntAddr.127.0.0.1.123" to an ObjectIdentity.  Splitting it into `ObjectIdentity('IP-MIB', 'ipAdEntAddr', '127.0.0.1.123')` or into `ObjectIdentity('IP-MIB', 'ipAdEntAddr', 127, 0, 0, 1, 123)` doesn't work, as resolveWithMib fails with "Bad IP address syntax"

Answer (score 0):

Considering `ipAddrTable` is indexed by just one column (`ipAdEntAddr`), I think this should resolve just fine:

```
ObjectIdentity('IP-MIB', 'ipAdEntAddr', '127.0.0.1')
```

API-wise, [ObjectIdentity](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity) understands MIB and object names as first two parameters, the rest should be individual sub-indices. So if `123` index component would make sense, it should go separately:

```
ObjectIdentity('IP-MIB', 'ipAdEntAddr', '127.0.0.1', 123)
```

Comment: How I would I know programatically that it would need to be split as ('127.0.0.1', '123') rather than ('127', '0' ,'0', '1', '123') (or some other similar such variation)?

Comment: There are only two forms of index currently supported by pysnmp: either all OIDs or a tuple of indices. Pysnmp can take the OID and break it down onto indices and vice versa. There is a special SMI protocol for serializing values into a series of sub-OIDs. If you want to deal with some other form of index, perhaps you should use pysnmp to give you index definition, look (programmatically) into the types comprising the index and try to match your input against respective indices. That's what pysnmp does under the hood, so you can check it out for inspiration.